# Invalid tokens with graph explorer

Tags: azure-active-directory

is it possible to revoke all azure ad tokens with graph explorer?
As with this PowerShell cmdlet: Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken

BR
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Graph API in the graph explorer:

`POST https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{user_id}/invalidateAllRefreshTokens?api-version`

For more details, refer to this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#invalidate-all-refresh-tokens-for-a-user).

Answer (score 0):

Short: I don't think so.

What is the goal ? Is it to disallow a single user, or all users in a tenant?
There isn't a refresh token for a user, only an access token as this is a single page application using the implicit grant flow. I think the best that they can do is to turn off user consented access. What I don't know is whether user consent can be turned off per app, per user, or only across an organization. I have no idea about the granularity of that control. I've only heard of this type of control so I've never done it myself.

Access tokens granted to GE last 60 minutes.